# Insert rows into another table based on column value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (shipments and stocks).

shipments table (id, item_id, quantity, expiry_date, status)

stocks table (id, shipment_id, item_id, quantity, expiry_date)

status can be either **Accepted** or **Returned**.

I want to create a trigger to insert into stocks table only the shipment items that are **Accepted**

This is my code, i don't know how to achieve this.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_stocks AFTER INSERT ON shipments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF shipments.status = 'Accepted' THEN
   INSERT INTO stocks (shipment_id, item_id, quantity, expiry_date)
   VALUES (NEW.shipments, NEW.item_id, NEW.quantity, NEW.expiry_date);
 END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please share more details. What exactly is not working with the given trigger? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: *`NEW.shipments`* No such column. Maybe, `NEW.id`?

Comment: i used NEW.id. And when i inserted values into shipments table the following error comes. ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'shipments' in field list

Comment: I think the issue is here. 'IF shipments.status = 'Accepted' THEN'

Comment: Please add all error messages to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but when checking the status of the new row you should use the `NEW` keyword, like you've done in the `insert` statement.

Additionally, the shipment ID should be takes from `NEW.id`, not `NEW.shipments` (which doesn't exist).

```
IF NEW.status = 'Accepted' THEN
   INSERT INTO stocks (shipment_id, item_id, quantity, expiry_date)
   VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.item_id, NEW.quantity, NEW.expiry_date);
END IF;
```